# How can i regex validate a user submitted password which is encoded in PBKDF2

Tags: java, passwords, password-hash, zul

I am trying to validate the password strength for a user when an admin creates a new  profile.

When the form gets submitted to the backend, i get the password encrypted in PBKDF2.
I have to validate it in java, i cannot validate it in zul framework script(My FrontEnd script).

Can someone help me how to **decrypt PBKDF2** and validate the password strength with regex.

Comment: The entire point of a hash is to make that completely impossible.

Comment: Any validation should be done client-side before it is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption can be reversed to recover the original message, but PBKDF2 is not an encryption algorithm. It's a key derivation algorithm, which is designed to be irreversible.

Also, note that it's not secure to perform the PBKDF2 hashing on the front end, and then submit it to the back end which matches it against a stored copy to authenticate a user. This is equivalent of storing the passwords in plain text. The secret transmitted by the front end should never be stored, only its hash.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of PBKDF2 is to ***ensure*** that the resulting hash cannot be decrypted to recover the original password.

Simply put, if you want to apply any complexity verification to the password you MUST do it before the password is encrypted, i.e. at the front end where the password is typed by the user.

There is no solution at the back end with a hashed password.